Calculating total pay when hourly rates are different after 40 hours worked
I am trying to calculate the total pay based on hours worked. The rates are €12 for the first 40 hours, €15 for each overtime hour.
I have made the following sheet:

The hours worked are formatted as follows: [h]:mm;@.
The total is calculated using =SUM(C3:C8) and is formatted as follows: [h]:mm:ss;@.
My plan was to do something like this: =IF(C11>40;(40*12)+((C11-40)*15);C11\*12), but it does not work. I also tried using =HOURS(C11) to extract hours singularly, but it uses 24 hours instead of a clean number.
I am pretty much lost at this point.

Try: =MAX(C11*24-40,0)*15+MIN(C11*24,40)*12

Use the following formula:


• Formula used in cell C12
=MAX(C11*24-40,0)*Overtime_Pay+MIN(C11*24,40)*Regular_Pay



Where: Regular_Pay is a defined name for cell F2
Where: Overtime_Pay is a defined name for cell F3


You can also define name for the Paid Hours as Paid_Hours which is 40 and use as
=MAX(C11*24-Paid_Hours,0)*Overtime_Pay+MIN(C11*24,Paid_Hours)*Regular_Pay


If minutes are not needed in the calculation, you can use the following formula to extract hours from the total and multiply the first 40 hours by 12, the extra hours by 15:
=IF(ROUNDDOWN(MIN(C11*24);0)>40;(40*12)+((ROUNDDOWN(MIN(C11*24);0)-40)*15);ROUNDDOWN(MIN(C11*24);0)*12)

In this specific case, ROUNDDOWN(MIN(C11*24);0) returns 41.

Ended up using part of your formula to extract the hours (as I don't really need minutes), then used the hours with the IF written in my question. Worked flawlessly, thank you!

@dave166 can you post your formula by editing my answer, so it will help someone in the future by mentioning the same, that you need hours and not minutes. And Thank you very much!
